# ResizableBox doesn't wrap contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, word-wrap

I'm using `ResizeBox` and want to wrap the contents inside of it. However, it's not working. The code is in the sandbox here. I've tried with other components too (other than `div`) and the same problem happens.

```
import React from "react";
import { ResizableBox } from "react-resizable";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";
import "./style.css";

const Box = () => {
  return (
    <ResizableBox className="box borderBlack" width={200} height={200} axis="y">
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
      <div>tXYZ!!</div>
    </ResizableBox>
  );
};

export default Box;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-forked-u5dwp?file=/src/App.tsx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.react-resizable {
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: Excellent. I also want to know - is there a way I can "Squish" the contents instead? (e.g. make the font size smaller, or if it's a graph, reduce its height, similar to the effect of zooming out using the mousewheel)?

Comment: i think, reduct font size is not good solution, because, the rows can be over than 1000

Comment: I have a use case where I want the user to be able to make a chart component inside the box larger on the y-axis when the increase the size of the box (and vice-versa for decreasing the size of the box). If it was just text - I would be in agreement with you

Comment: i don't have idea